# watchman: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1

Tags: android, node.js, facebook, react-native, watchman

I'm on Ubuntu 15.10 and I am developing an Android (SDK 23) app using react-native (0.20.0).  I'm using node 5.6.0 and npm 3.6.0.

I encountered a watchman error when running `react-native start`

```
ERROR  watchman--no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code 127 watchman: 
error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object 
file: No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/rachael/Dev/InstaGo/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:198:18)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:471:12)
```

When I run `sudo find / -name libpcre.so.1` the following is returned:

```
/home/rachael/.linuxbrew/lib/libpcre.so.1
/home/rachael/.linuxbrew/Cellar/pcre/8.38/lib/libpcre.so.1
```

I've tried reinstalling watchman:

```
make uninstall

git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git 
cd watchman 
git checkout v4.1.0 # the latest stable release .
/autogen.sh 
./configure 
make 
sudo make install
```

I also tried it with linuxbrew:

```
npm r -g watchman 
brew update && brew upgrade
brew install watchman
```

which gave a completely different error:

```
A non-recoverable condition has triggered.  Watchman needs your help!
The triggering condition was at timestamp=1407695600: inotify-add-watch(/my/path) -> Cannot allocate memory
All requests will continue to fail with this message until you resolve
the underlying problem.  You will find more information on fixing this at
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify-add-watch
```

The Facebook troubleshooting page for this is extremely vague and I couldn't resolve that error either.

I'm very new to this so I'd appreciate any help with this issue.  Thank you for your time.

## Update

Install watchman via linuxbrew.

When using linuxbrew remember to include the following commands before installing any formula:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
brew update && brew upgrade
```

Then install the latest release of watchman:

```
brew install --HEAD watchman
```

Then increase the amount of inotify user instances, user watches and queued events:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_instances=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
echo fs.inotify.max_queued_events=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Now watchman should be working and `react-native start` should run fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem that you posted is a ldconfig related problem; since the pcre binaries are not installed in the system library path, your runtime linker cannot resolve them at runtime and thus cannot start the watchman binary.

I cannot help you directly resolve that part of the problem, but it sounds like the later steps you tried put you in a better position.

Please note that the current released version of watchman is 4.5.0; the directions you were following are outdated (Could you tell me where you found those directions?)
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html always has the current information.

Now, to the poison issue:

The error message you saw included a (broken, sorry!) link to https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify_add_watch that has some explanation about what is happening.

You need to read this section on setting up your system limits correctly:
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#system-specific-preparation

and once done, you can clear the state by running `watchman shutdown-server`

Did that help?  I'd like to understand which parts of this you found vague so that I can improve it for others!

Comment: Hi @WezFurlong I was using this link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started-linux.html#installing-watchman.  Maybe just include those commands I have put in my **Update** section under my question. It clearly shows the commands needed for increasing the different values for inotify.  Would be a lot nicer for newbie's like myself. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In relation to the **completely different error**.

You have watchman running already, so when you do `react-native start` it tries to start another one.

1. First run `watchman shutdown-server`
2. Open your emulator again
3. Call `react-native start` in terminal
4. Open your app in the emulator.

Everything should work. It did for me.